# NomicLabsHardhatPluginError: The constructor for contracts/FundMe.sol:FundMe has 1 parameters but 0 arguments were provided instead

Tags: solidity, etherscan

I'm trying to verify and submit my contract source code to etherscan using a headset, but I'm getting the following error and I don't understand how to solve it. I've read through the code and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Please can anyone advise?
The error that I am getting when I run:

```
NomicLabsHardhatPluginError: The constructor for contracts/FundMe.sol:FundMe has 1 parameters
but 0 arguments were provided instead.
```

heres all the code `FundMe.sol` code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.8;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
import "./PriceConverter.sol";

error NotOwner();

contract FundMe {
    using PriceConverter for uint256;

    mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;
    address[] public funders;

    address public /* immutable */ i_owner;
    uint256 public constant MINIMUM_USD = 50 * 10 ** 18;

    AggregatorV3Interface public priceFeed;
    
    constructor(address priceFeedAddress) {
        i_owner = msg.sender;
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(priceFeedAddress);
    }


    function fund() public payable {
        require(msg.value.getConversionRate(priceFeed) >= MINIMUM_USD, "You need to spend more ETH!");
     
        addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        funders.push(msg.sender);
    }
    
        modifier onlyOwner {
        if (msg.sender != i_owner) revert NotOwner();
        _;
    }
    
    function withdraw() payable onlyOwner public {
        for (uint256 funderIndex=0; funderIndex < funders.length; funderIndex++){
            address funder = funders[funderIndex];
            addressToAmountFunded[funder] = 0;
        }
        funders = new address[](0);
 
        (bool callSuccess, ) = payable(msg.sender).call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        require(callSuccess, "Call failed");
    }

    fallback() external payable {
        fund();
    }

    receive() external payable {
        fund();
    }

}
```

and also the `01-deploy-fund-me.js`  to see the code of verify

```js
const { getNamedAccounts, deployments, network } = require("hardhat")
const { networkConfig, developmentChains } = require("../helper-hardhat-config")
const { verify } = require("../utils/verify")

module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
    const chainId = network.config.chainId

    let ethUsdPriceFeedAddress
    if (chainId == 31337) {
        const ethUsdAggregator = await deployments.get("MockV3Aggregator")
        ethUsdPriceFeedAddress = ethUsdAggregator.address
    } else {
        ethUsdPriceFeedAddress = networkConfig[chainId]["ethUsdPriceFeed"]
    }
    log("----------------------------------------------------")
    log("Deploying FundMe and waiting for confirmations...")

    const fundMe = await deploy("FundMe", {
        from: deployer,
        args: [ethUsdPriceFeedAddress],
        log: true,
        // we need to wait if on a live network so we can verify properly
        waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1,
    })
    //log("----------------------------------------------------")
    log(`FundMe deployed at ${fundMe.address}`)

    if (
        !developmentChains.includes(network.name) &&
        process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY
    ) {
        await verify(fundMe.address, [ethUsdPriceFeedAddress])
    }
    log("----------------------------------------------------")
}

module.exports.tags = ["all", "fundme"]
```

Please help me!

Comment: If you try to just deploy the contract without verifying it does it work?

Comment: yes! works fine... the problem is etherscan plugin

Comment: Maybe try to generate new api keys for etherscan.

Comment: Well I think my problem was rinkeby network,  it works so fine with kovan network! Thats was my solution, just change the testnet network! Thank u for everything